# Recovering Component ref from react JSX.Element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have a method in a class:

```
class Foo {
    getElement : JSX.element () {
        return <Component ref={React.createRef()} />
    }
}
```

Like in normal React.js code (without typescript), I'd like to be able to get the component itself, like so:

```
const foo = new Foo();
const component = foo.getElement().ref.current;
```

However, the `JSX.Element` class only has the properties `key`, `props` and `type`.

How do I get the component in typescript?

---

I've been stuck for a while on this, as:

- First, getElement had a return type of Component, but I didn't realise what's actually returned is an Element
- After realising an Element was returned - by looking at the return type of , I used the generic Element class.
- I've gotten to the point above where it's finally returning properly, but it has all the properties I need but the `ref`.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it may be an [issue](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/33530) within Reacts type declerations.

---

A solution is to stop *anonymously* using the ref, and group it with the Element, i.e:

```
type RefElement = { ref: RefObject<Component>, element: JSX.Element };

class Foo {
    getRefElement: RefElement () {
        const ref = createRef<Component>();
        return {
            ref: ref,
            element: <Component ref={ref} />
        }
    }
}
```

...

```
const foo = new Foo();

...

const component = foo.getRefElement().ref.current;
```